descending and ascending index firestore
I want to have two indexes in my firestore.
Both should have array keywords, and be ordered by time posted (timestamp)
One needs to be ordered by timestamp descending and other one needs to be ordered by timestamp ascending
if I create one of them I cannot create other one.
The error i am getting while trying to create second index is: uh oh something went wrong
What is the way to do this, or is there a better way?
I dont want to get whole collection and then order them, I want to load them in chunks.
firestore.collection(collection).orderBy("timestamp", direction).startAfter(lastSnapshot).limit(10).get().addOnCompleteListener(......)


Why do you say "if I create one of them I cannot create the other one"? What exactly happens when you try to create the second one? Do you get any errors?
